# Spring Cloud Contract Variable inside URL Path

Tags: spring, groovy, spring-cloud-contract

My URL consists of variable inside the URL path as shown in the below request. I am not able to call this this request. Any idea if I can use regex?

```
request {
   method 'GET'
   url ('/accounts/groups/{Id}/locations) {
      queryParameters {
         parameter('Id', "568b444ae73eb5883d4a")
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: you can provide regex expression in url value(consumer(regex('/accounts/groups/[0-9\(\)]+/locations'))). By the way I think above one is path variable definitely not the query parameter.

Comment: Is there any way to use pathParam in groovy DSL instead of queryParameters? Jayway restassured supports pathParam.

Comment: As I already mentioned you can use regex in url like `url value(consumer(regex('/accounts/groups/[0-9()]+/loca‌​tions')))` or just hardcode the value in the url /accounts/groups/123456/locations

Comment: Hardcoding of url worked. Thanks Barath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need query parameters as your id is in the URL. What you need is an **alphanumeric** regex like so:
`url value(consumer(regex('/accounts/groups/[a-zA-Z0-9]+/locations')))`

More about `Spring Cloud Contract` regex [here](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Greenwich.RC2/multi/multi_contract-dsl.html#_regular_expressions).